# No user link in auth section of Django admin

Tags: python, django, authorization

I am trying to implement a custom user model, but under the auth url `localhost:8000/admin/auth/` of the Django admin website my model is not showing up.

I found an answer at the link below to the overall problem, but when trying to implement it myself I still do not see the users in the auth section of the Django admin.

[No “Users” link in “Auth” section of Django admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417303/no-users-link-in-auth-section-of-django-admin-site)

what am I doing wrong here ?

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm

CustomUser = get_user_model()


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = (
        "email",
        "username",
    )

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {"fields": ("email", "password")}),
        ("Permissions", {"fields": ("is_admin", "groups", "user_permissions")}),
    )


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("email", "username")


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("email", "username")
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem:

1. created my own user model
2. in admin, groups and my user model are not listed in same (auth) section

My solution was basically to put django groups into my app to have it displayed in the same section, because django creates admin sections for each app.

1. create your own group model as proxy object in your `models.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group as DjangoGroup

...

class Group(DjangoGroup):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = _('group')
        verbose_name_plural = _('groups')
```

2. (un)register your models in `admin.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin as DjangoGroupAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group as DjangoGroup
from .models import CustomUser, Group

...

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)

admin.site.unregister(DjangoGroup)
admin.site.register(Group, DjangoGroupAdmin)
```

Comment: what is the _ ?

Comment: it lists groups and users under the same admin section now . . .  but it doesn't do anything for auth, it actually removes groups from the url `localhost:8000/admin/auth/` and thus renders as a 404

Comment: _ is used for Translations, you can just use strings.

Comment: In my solution you do not longer use the django auth app as the aim was to place User and Groups with your own app. I was not able to find a proper solution where you can display own models in django sections/apps (like djangos auth app). The whole Problem exists because django groups models of an app together and you try to group your model into another app.